# Nesting Navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am struggling to figure out how nesting navigators works. I want to render my tabs and my stack of screens. I have tried a couple different things, including my last attempt which was out of confusion and just trying things. Any help is appreciated! Thankyou.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
//    const dispatch = useDispatch();
//    const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#F60081',
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#F1F1F1'
        }
      }}
     
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={maps}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Maps',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker-circle" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>    
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home, MyTabs} options={{headerShown: false}}/>        
        <Stack.Screen name="VenueDetails" component= {VenueDetailsScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can group your screens into a stack navigator, and then put that navigator as screen in the bottom tab navigator.

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/nested-navigation) of a nested navigation. For your example, looks like you want to put a tab navigator inside a stack navigator, so in your App. you can do the following:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The above have one stack navigator on the top layer. Inside that stack navigator, you will 3 screens, Home, MyTabs, and VenueDetails. Inside the MyTabs screen, you have a Tab navigator.

Comment: Okay, so what if wanted the tab navigator across all my screens, I want the bottom tab to be seen from each page. I updated my question to show what I am doing to currently display it across each screen, but I am not sure if that is the correct way to do so?Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help me!

Comment: in that case, you just render the MyTabs component inside your App.js.

Comment: Maybe I miscommunicated. I would still like to render the stack as well. I want to navigate through screens, while having the tab on every single screen. Again, Thank you for taking the time out of your day for helping me, I cannot say thank you enough!

Comment: What do you want in your stack? And which tab would you like to show that stack?

Comment: I would like to have the two pages in my stack, Home and VenueDetails. I also would like to have the bottom tab that is implemented above on every single screen.